# How two different domains to be viewed in the single browser?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml

I have two different application having different domains, want to make a site where its show both sites in a single page.[Without using Iframe].

Comment: May you use some server-side programming language, like PHP or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6):

You could use good old frames (not IFRAME):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>This &amp; That</title>
</head>
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
  <frame src="http://site1.example.com/">
  <frame src="http://site2.example.com/">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, pretty much the last valid use for frames, IMO.

Comment: Max is 10 per day (or a bit above that). You apparently just don't vote that much ;)

Comment: 30, actually. On a busy day I run out.

Answer (score 5):

Too bad - IFRAMEs would be a simple and effective solution.

Another reasonably simple solution would be to use a 3rd server, one of your own, to aggregate pages from the other two.

I can't think of a sensible way to do this in the client browser without IFRAMEs.

Comment: You'd write a Web app that itself acts as a HTTP client to 2 or more other sites, pulls in their text, combines it into a single document and returns that to the original client's browser.

Comment: @DhrubaJyoti Aggregating pages is the easy part - I'd like to know how you're going to display them with out frames/iframes.

Comment: Heh, once you have all the content, you can re-arrange their DIVs any way you please. That's definitely not hard, assuming you know the other guys' page structure. Even if you don't, you could display the 2 pages side by side in a table or something.

Comment: Getting their CSS, JS, etc. not to affect each other could be tough, though. Lots of post-processing and nasty edge cases involved, plus issues with CSS positioning, differing doctypes, and more.

Comment: Well, we're assuming those pages are not purely random but well known in their structure, if not their exact content.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm) in DynamicDrive website. It uses **AJAX** to dynamically load the content of an HTML page into a DIV element.
This will only work for local files (trying to include one page into another page on the same domain), but if you may use PHP on server-side, you can use **jQuery** to solve this out ([check out this article](http://www.sitegrind.nl/jquery/jquery-load-function-get-content-from-other-websites)).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot not display diffrent domains in the same page without iframes or frames.
The cannot be bceuse of browser security.

Comment: A proxy script allows you to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Welcome to site A</h1>
Here is the weather from site B <hr />
<?php
   include("http://siteb.com/weather.htm");
?>
```

Of course, in practice you'd need to parse the DOM returned from siteB to ensure that the composite output was well formed - i.e. stripping out the ... and XML sugar. And strip out or erqrite any references to files on siteb contained within the HTML - such as javascript, images etc.

And bear in mind that this is going to break any fancy CSS.

C.